# Remove space of folder using php

Tags: php

I am uploading zip file using php, when i extract the folder using,

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open("test.zip") === TRUE) {
$zip->extractTo($pat."/");
$zip->close();
}
```

all are working fine. But if suppose, the uploaded zip format file name is 
for ex(new folder) that is space between name means. It not possible for me to get the name of folder.

Comment: if folder name is "new folder" i want to retrieve image file inside the folder is not possible for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not necessary that the spaces are kept you can use the "ereg_replace" function:

```
$var =$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$name= ereg_replace(" ","_",$var);
```

So "new folder" will become "new_folder".

Comment: This function "ereg_replace" has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

instead use preg_replace or just follow the link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer,

```
$var =$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$name= str_replace(" ","\ ",$var);
```